# What is this song that plays in Hunter x Hunter?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

I can't find it anywhere, but it's played 3 separate times...

- 20:48 season 1 episode 26 "then x and x after"
- 16:44 season 2 episode 11 "ging x and x gon"
- 18:47 season 3 episode 10 "very x sharp x eye"

Comment: This might help other people identify soundtracks, it has a list of every soundtrack used in each episode with their timestamps: [HxH 2011 OST list](https://sites.google.com/site/hxh2011ostlist/) [Source of the list](https://www.reddit.com/r/HunterXHunter/comments/27xe3j/list_of_soundtrack_used_for_hunter_x_hunter_2011/)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have names but, the other guy covered it pretty much. These playlists would be to your liking most likely: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7636F65EA6C7228C, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFeYG_GYxoQ&list=PL24ACDF1A713BEE0B

***The ones that closely matched to the ones in query were:***

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jABvp01nr2E

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCgGDxHjqD4

Answer (score 2):

The soundtrack isn't included in the original soundtrack CD, so it is **unreleased**, you can't search it by soundtrack name. [This list](https://sites.google.com/site/hxh2011ostlist/arcs/4-yorknew-city-arc-37-58) shows you soundtracks included in every episodes. See *ep. 37* because *ep. 26* doesn't have a list (cuz it's a filler, doesn't include in either Blu-ray or DVD).

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about the slow song that played with Gon and Aunt Mito, it’s the slow version of “Departure” in the intro of Hunter x Hunter. Here’s the link: https://youtu.be/_WxStK8Puz0

Answer (score -3):

The song is "JUST AWAKE" from "FEAR, and Loathing in Las Vegas".
Here a [YouTube link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP0Ej28JeCs)

Comment: Certainly not this. "Just Awake" is the ending song.